# Add http://192.168.64.2:8000 domain for Authorized redirect URIs

Tags: oauth-2.0, ip-address, google-oauth

I am trying to add google Authorized redirect URIs
I have added two domain for locally test 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/    and 
http://localhost:8000/app/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/

The above two domain works fine

but when I want to add 
http://192.168.64.2:8000/app/oauth/complete/google-oauth2

it shows bellow error

```
Invalid Redirect: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).
Invalid Redirect: domain must be added to the authorized domains list before submitting.
```

What is the problem actually to add http://192.168.64.2:8000/app/oauth/complete/google-oauth2 as a domain for Authorized redirect URIs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t add an IP address that is not 127.0.0.1. If you want to add a location like that, you need to setup a server and have it accessible from a public www domain.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can't add ip address to the authorized urls

AWS ec2 instance has two `PublicIPAddress` and `PublicDnsName`

The `PublicDnsName` looks like `ec2-113-34-20-346.app-north-4.compute.amazonaws.com` you have to check your instance for more detail.

add the `PublicDnsName` to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`

### settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ec2-113-34-20-346.app-north-4.compute.amazonaws.com', 'ec2-113-34-20-346.app-north-4.compute.amazonaws.com:8000']

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://ec2-113-34-20-346.app-north-4.compute.amazonaws.com', 'http://ec2-113-34-20-346.app-north-4.compute.amazonaws.com:8000']
```

### In google Console add this to authorized urls

```
http://ec2-113-34-20-346.app-north-4.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
```